# Simplifying multiple for each loops in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, foreach, loops

in my prev question i was suggested with LINQ solution. It was great and simple. I tried to solve next similar but a bit diff problem with similar approach but i failed.

how can i make the below code better

```
    For Each Item As ListViewItem In RoomsListView.Items
        For Each Item1 As Room In myBookedRooms
            If Item1.UIN = Item.SubItems(1).Text Then
                Item.Checked = True
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: could you explain the code as my VB.NET is bad I'm unable to understand the relation between `RoomsListView.Items` and `myBookedRooms`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - can read but not write VB...

In C# Linq, your query would be something like:

```
var query = from room in RoomsListView.Items
    from bookedRoom in myBookedRooms 
    where ((Room)bookedRoom).UIN == room.SubItems(1).Text
    select room;

foreach (var room in query)
{
    room.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: I tried to convert above code to vb.net using http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ and after that i used it in my project but it says 'Join' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection

Comment: really? My code doesn't use Join (although it did have an "==" bug that I've just fixed!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Join` for that. Here is a `C#` sample:

```
var itemsToUpdate = RoomsListView.Items
                        .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                        .Join(myBookedRooms,
                                   Item => Item.SubItems(1).Text,
                                   Item1 => Item1.UIN,
                                   (Item, Item1) => Item);

foreach (var item in itemsToUpdate)
    item.Checked = true;
```

Comment: I tried to convert above code to vb.net using http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ and after that i used it in my project but it says 'Join' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection

Comment: @KoolKabin, updated. I do always forget that such collection are not strongly typed.